# Bouncing Out Of Method In IBM Websphere Studio Enterprise Developer - Java Code

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I have a call to a method in another class in my Action Dispatcher, that goes like this:

```
...
CaseManagementLetter cml = new CaseManagementLetter();
String content = cml.generateLettersByClaimantsPDF(cids, request, response,     currentUser);
...
```

The method opening looks like this:

```
public String generateLettersByClaimantsPDF(List cids, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, User currentUser) throws Exception
{
HashMap ids = new HashMap();
...
```

Immediately after this line, the code bounces back out into the previous method.

I have check the variables and they are all properly populated, and I have checked the break points and they are all properly placed to follow the code, step-by-step.

So why is it bouncing out of my method like this?

Edit: This message seems to consistently appear after being bounced out.

```
[7/17/13 15:59:59:978 EDT] 312f312f SharedPool    I J2CA0086W: Shareable connection   MCWrapper id 34aa34aa  Managed connection  com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl@32ca32ca   State:STATE_TRAN_WRAPPER_INUSE
from resource jdbc/WPM_DataSource was used within a local transaction containment   boundary.
```

Comment: So while calling `new HashMap()`..  it jumps out?  or the line afterwards?  It could be that an there was an exception.  You probably aren't handling it inside that method call because that method does declare that it `throws Exception`

Comment: I've tried placing everything within the Try block (which handles this Exception), but never hits my catch block.

Although, at the end of my code, it DOES tell me that I have an Apache servlet exception, so I won't rule that out entirely.

Comment: What happens when it bounces out?  Have you tried catching `Throwable` for troubleshooting purposes?  No errors/exceptions show?

Comment: None apparent, though I admit to being unfamiliar with dispatch exception handling (and am still rather green on dispatch itself!), so I'm not entirely sure what I need to be looking out for here.